# How to create a service for using the user uid when getting data from firestore? angular/firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get data from firestore using the user's uid because I am storing data (drills) under the following firestore path: drills/[user.uid]/userDrills/[drill.id]

I implemented storing data by uid because I wanted each user to only have access to their data (drills). Before I implemented this, I had one drill service file that contained all CRUD methods for firestore, however I am not able to get the uid from the auth state in time to inject it into the query. Even getting the uid in the service's constructor, did not work.

My solution at the moment is not using a service. This means that I have to get the user's uid in three different components (list, edit/delete, and new)...

Does anybody have a solution for this? Is there a better way to get the uid and then run the query? If not, would it be a better solution to just handle user rights in firestore by creating rules?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {AngularFireAuth} from "@angular/fire/auth";
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection} from 
 "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {Drill} from "../drill.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drill-list',
  templateUrl: './drill-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drill-list.component.css']
})


export class DrillListComponent implements OnInit {

  drills: Observable<any[]>;
  drillsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Drill>;
  userId: any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.afAuth.authState
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.userId = data.uid;
      this.drillsCollection = this.afs.collection('drills/' + this.userId + '/userDrills',
          ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
      this.drills = this.getDrills();
    });

}

 getDrills(): Observable<Drill[]> {
   return this.drillsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Drill;
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         return { id, ...data};
      });
    }));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by keeping the UID in an observable on the auth service. I use a "fetchUid" method to pipe and filter out falsy values, and to cancel the stream just use an operator like the "first" operator.

Something like:

```
// in auth service
private uidSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
private uid$ = this.uidSubject.asObservable();

fetchUid() {
    return this.uid$.pipe(
        filter(v => v), // only allows the non falsy value through
        first(), // cancels stream after first
    );
}

// component
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.fetchUid().pipe(
        // do stuff with uid
    ); // handle subscribe if needed
}
```